# Only active product count on Magento Category

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to display the number of products in each category, using this code to I want to display subcategories of category `id:3` . It is showing but it included disabled and invisible products.

```
<?php
$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3)->getChildrenCategories();
?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($cats as $category): ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?>(<?php echo $category->getProductCount(); ?>)</a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Is there any good solution so that I can get the exact count of categories that are Enabled and active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
you need check active filter acondition and for this you can use below code 


    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);

    echo $products->count();
```

Comment: It won't give the exact number of products visible in a category. there are a lot more conditions for configurable products and also simple in stock products.

Answer (score 1):

Without any regard to Magento programming conventions, that piece of code should look like this:

```
<?php
$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3)->getChildrenCategories();
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($cats as $category): ?>
<?php $count = $collection->addCategoryFilter($category)->getSize(); ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?>(<?php echo $count ?>)</a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

But do the world a favor and organize the code properly.

Comment: It is displaying correctly only for first subcategory, and first subcategory product count is repeating for all other subcategory also please check http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e31cd034f

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `$category->getProductCollection()` in foreach, and pass it through the Visibility filters, but it will have a bit larger impact on server in that case. Basically, the trick is to pass the collections through the two Visibility filters. Try to find a way not to load a product collection in each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Loading collection and using multiple attribute filter is not a proper way and this won't filter associated product and it's stock levels.

This piece of code with do all together,

```
$categoryId = 32; // Replace with your category

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                 ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                 ->load($categoryId);
Mage::register('current_category', $category);

$products = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getProductCollection();

echo $products->getSize();
```